# How can I invoke a buildsystem containing commands that exceed Windows' command line string length limitation?

Tags: windows, cmake, makefile, git-bash

I have a firmware program I am trying to build using CMake on Windows. I am using a GitBash shell to run a "Make" command and create a makefile, however windows can has a limit of 8188 characters, which the makefile exceeds. As a result the build fails.

The cross-compiler I am using is the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain and my program has to be run on Windows.

The command I use to generate the make files is shown below:

`$ cmake -DDFU_FILENAME=dfu.zip -DKEY_DIR=${HOME}/Downloads -DARM_NONE_EABI_PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/11.3 rel1/arm-none-eabi" -DSDK_ROOT_DIR=${HOME}/fatfs/stix_nrf_sdk -DVERSION=259 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../stix_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/Arm GNU Toolchain arm-none-eabi/11.3 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" ..`

The expectation is for the makefile to build successfully without Windows truncating the file. However there was a cut-off at the character limit which resulted in the following error message:

`$ make [  0%] Building C object CMakeFiles/stix_fw.dir/main.c.obj arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fstac'; did you mean '-fstats'? arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated. make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stix_fw.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/stix_fw.dir/main.c.obj] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:118: CMakeFiles/stix_fw.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2`

Comment: Normally, CMake is able to generate (and actually generates) command lines which doesn't suffer from OS-specific limitations. See e.g. [that bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16771). Probably, your toolchain incorrectly defines the target system. Could you provide more information about it?

Answer (score 0):

Note relevant docs (which state that the limitation is actually 8191 characters): [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation).

CMake has logic to detect when commandlines are too long and adjust what it generates accordingly. See also https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/705. So what you're encountering might be a bug or an unhandled case.

I'd try running from a different shell like PowerShell and see if it has the same limitation.

If that doesn't work, or you don't like that approach, you'll probably have to use one of [the suggested workarounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation#how-to-work-around-the-limitation)- namely, moving some of the things in the command line into a file. MSVC has a mechanism for this- [command files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-command-files). [A similar mechanism is in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) and Clang.